# Make JPanel background transparent without text overlapping

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, transparent

I am making something that resembles a subtitle player that will go over a video.

I would like to make the background transparent so that the box that the text is in will not interfere with the movie/TV show playing behind it.  I have tried 2 ways to do this and each way results in the same problem.  The text does not disappear when the next sentence appears.  If the background is a color (Eg: Color.red), then this works fine.  After a certain time, I call text.setText("next sentence"), but this does not work with a transparent background. The relevant code is as follows. text is a JTextField

I should mention the video is not in this program.  This program is ONLY subtitles.

First way:

```
text.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

Second way: (using a transparent image)

```
Graphics c = myPicture.getGraphics();
text.paintAll(c);
```

I update the text like this.

```
Thread.sleep(Graphix.subtitles.get(counter).getStart());
text.setText(Graphix.subtitles.get(counter).getText());
```

This also makes it overlap.

```
text.setForeground(Color.blue);
text.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
text.setOpaque(false);
```

The relevant code from Main is as follows.

```
final JFrame JFwindow = new JFrame("Subtitles");
JFwindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
JFwindow.getContentPane().add(new Subtitles()); 
JFwindow.setSize(1300, 150);
JFwindow.setUndecorated(true);
JFwindow.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0f));
JFwindow.pack();
JFwindow.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: How are you playing the video?  How are you making the `JPanel` transparent?  Are you calling `repaint" on the panel?

Comment: Updated with information!

Comment: `text is a JTextField` - I would use a JLabel. A label is transparent by default and is used for displaying text. A JTextField is used to edit/type text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Transparency is achieved by calling `JPanel#setOpaque` and passing it `false`.
- You should NEVER be calling `getGraphics`.  `getGraphics` and return `null` and is, at best, only as snap shot.  Once the `RepaintManager` starts a new paint cycle, the results of painting to it will be overridden.
- Using a tarnsparent color will only confuse the `RepaintManager` as it won't know that it needs to paint under the component
- Sleeping within the Event Dispatching Thread (EDT) will stop Swing from performing any updates (as well as process any events).  Instead I'd recommend using a `javax.swing.Timer`.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.
- If you're using the VLC bindings, then it can't be achieved
- Don't forget to make all the parent containers that the sub titles are contained in transparent as well

Comment: Hmm, so what I have right now looks like it would have to be redone in order to achieve what I am attempting?  The Timer should solve this?